# Can't get webservice to recognize my parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, webmethod, pagemethods

It seems like this ought to be simple thing to do, but I can't invoke my web service call.  Here is my code:

```
var data = '{"deviceId":"e9b3f993-7ca1-442b-a5c2-001ab86e1af4","opid":202,"remarks":"fefawef"}';

$.ajax({
    url: 'MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
    data: data,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(response) {
        // Do stuff                                                      
    },
    error: function(xhr) {                          
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); // end $.ajax
```

At first glance, you might ask if it would be more appropriate to use POST instead of GET.  It probably would, but I'm using GET to avoid the nasty Internet Explorer 12030 error problem.

The signature of my web method looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)] 
public static string MyMethod(string deviceId, int opid, string remarks)
```

Finally, the error that I'm seeing is `Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: deviceId`.  I don't see what the problem could be.  `deviceId` is plainly indicated in the JSON string literal passed in.

Comment: Does your webservice support JSON parameters?  That's not exactly a universal thing.

Answer (score 2):

As you have used double quotes for the parameters you should use single quotes:

```
data = '{"deviceId":"e9b3f993-7ca1-442b-a5c2-001ab86e1af4","opid":202,"remarks":"fefawef"}'
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. How in the world did it even get far enough to say it couldn't find `deviceId` with such an obvious syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this isn't it.  `data` is actually the result of a function call which I copy-pasted into StackOverflow without checking the syntax.  I have updated the question to fix this.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon You are welcome, have you tried the dbaseman's solution?

Comment: Yes, I tried his solution and it produced a different error message.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the only issue, but your *data* Javascript isn't valid.  Per the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), this should be either a query string, or a JSON object (not a JSON string).  Try this:

```
var data = { deviceId: "e9b3f993-7ca1-442b-a5c2-001ab86e1af4", 
    opid: 202, 
    remarks: "fefawef" 
};
```

**Edit**

How about this:

```
var data = { d: '{"deviceId":"e9b3f993-7ca1-442b-a5c2-001ab86e1af4","opid":202,"remarks":"fefawef"}' };
```

Comment: This was the first thing I noticed when I looked at the code.

Comment: Doing this produces a different error message: `Invalid JSON primitive: e9b3f993-7ca1-442b-a5c2-001ab86e1af4.`

Comment: That would seem to indicate that it's expecting `deviceId` to be a JSON value? That doesn't make much sense... We can't really help you figure out error messages from a webservice that we dont really know anything about...

Comment: I did give the function signature for the web service in my original post. `deviceId` is a string.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon my mistake, I forgot that the .Net script-enabled service expects JSON format, not REST.  It looks like your syntax is correct now.  All I can suggest is to figure out a) what URL your browser is requesting (use Firebug or Fiddler to check) and b) what a valid URL would look like to produce a valid response from the service.

Comment: Following along in the debugger, it looks like my data is getting transformed into this: `deviceId=e9b3f993-7ca1-442b-a5c2-001ab86e1af4&opid=202&remarks=fefawef`.  It looks like a query string. Hmmmmm....

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Shot in the dark, but I recall that the MS services like to wrap data in a *d* property.  I wonder if my update above would work.